# How to create auto increment field

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I want to add auto increment value in a field in mongodb using php, without using counting the records and next number(count + 1) will be my increment value...
Or Is there any way to create array of autoincrement values in `mongodb`,`php` for example A customer having multiple emails and addresses then we can store it like `email[{1:'a@x.com',2:'demo@example.com'},...]` and also same for `address[{1:'Indore',2:'Dewas'},...]` So for uniqueness I want to set autoincrement value from each email and address..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you create two [collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-collection)

**First** to store the field for whichyou want to create **autoincrement number** like

```
// Inserting 2 records for which we want to create auto-increment numbers
db.autoincrementcollection.insert({
   field_id: "register_id",
   nextId: 0
},
{
   field_id: "user_id",
   nextId: 0
});

// Function is used to get the next autoincremented value
function getNextId(field)
{
   var ret = db.autoincrementcollection.findAndModify({
        query: { field_id: field },
        update: { $inc: { nextId: 1 } },
        new: true
   });    
   return ret.nextId;
}
```

**Second** in which you want to use the incremented number like

```
// inserting data in registration collection with register_id auto-increment number
db.registration.insert({
     _id: getNextId("register_id"),
     fname: "Rohan",
     lname:"Kumar"
});
// inserting data in user collection with user_id auto-increment number
db.users.insert({
     _id: getNextId("user_id"),
     name: "Rohan Kumar"
});
```

[findAndModify()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) may not work while code using **PHP** then you can use [find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) and/or [update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Refer **Docs** for [create-an-auto-incrementing-field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Comment: how do you implement the above using PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible we have to get max id form collection

```
db -> collection -> find() -> sort(array('id' => -1)) -> limit(1)
```

It return max id array. Add **db['id'] + 1**;

Every time need not store the auto-increment id in mongo

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be using autoincrement as identifier in MongoDb.
If you want to , refer 2 good methods given here :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

Answer (score 0):

This is my method for creating auto increment id in MongoDB PHP library:

```
private function get_last_id()
    {
        // put your connection string blow
        $client = new MongoDB\Client('');
        $counterCollection = $client->collection->counter;
        $counter["id"]=1;
        if ($counterCollection->count()<=0) {
            $insertOneResult = $counterCollection->insertOne($counter);
        } else {
            $filter  = [];
            $options = ['sort' => ['_id' => -1], 'limit' => 1];
            $doc = $counterCollection->findOne($filter, $options);
            $id=$doc->id+1;
            $updateResult = $counterCollection->updateOne(
            [ '_id' => $doc->_id ],
            [ '$set' => [ 'id' =>$id ]]
        );
            return $id;
        }
    }
```