# MongoDB - how to insert record using autoincrement functionality

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm following the documentation found here 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

I have two counters, one called locationid and the other called playhistid. 
This is what they look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "locationid",
    "seq" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : "playhistid",
    "seq" : 0
}
```

I've also created the following function:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );
```

Now I need a way to call `getNextSequence("locationid")` from PHP.
This is what my code looks like so far:

```
function add_playbook_history_record($location)
{
        $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.111:27017");
        $db = $m->testdb;
        $collection = $db->testcollection;
        $cursor = $collection->insert($location);
}
```

As you can see, I'm not calling the getNextSequence() function because I don't know how to do this in.  I found a similar question on this site:
[How to create auto increment field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921904/how-to-create-auto-increment-field-in-mongodb-and-php)

But... they don't actually show how to do this in PHP. They just show the material from the mongo docs.

**EDIT 1**

What I'm thinking of is trying to find a way to run the getNextSequence() using the db->command() method... and then adding a new item to my $location array like this:

```
$location["_id"] = value_from_db_command;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add _id field in $location.
And _id must you inc id.
Example:

```
function add_playbook_history_record($location)
{
        $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.111:27017");
        $db = $m->testdb;
        $collection = $db->testcollection;
        $location['_id'] = getNextSequence('playhistid')
        $cursor = $collection->insert($location);
}
```

*My recommendation: add upsert in findAndModify*

**It will work for you:**

```
    function getNextSequence($name)
    {
        $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.111:27017"); // In a real project, you do not need all the time to re-create the connection
        $db = $m->testdb;
        $collection = $db->counters;
        $result =  $collection->findAndModify(
            ['_id' => $name],
            ['$inc' => ['seq' => 1]],
            ['seq' => true],
            ['new' => true, 'upsert' => true]
        );
        if (isset($result['seq']))
        {
            return $result['seq'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**In a real project, you do not need all the time to re-create the connection**

You can create the MongoDatabase (this pattern singelton)

```
class MongoDatabase{
    private function __construct(){}
    public static function getInstance(){...} // return MongoClient
}
```

and call need method

```
MongoDatabase::getInstance()->selectCollection('counters')->findAndModify(...)
```

Comment: can you explain what the upsert is for?  Also, how is php supposed to "know" what the getNextSequence() function is? Can you explain? Should the code read "$db->getNextSequence"?

Comment: Of course. upsert - mean that, if the entry does not exist in the collection, it will create.
As for the method is much simpler. You must write it on the php.
(Updated the example above)

Comment: Maxim, I'm heading out of the office now but i will review your updated answer first thing tomorrow!! thanks.  but my next question is what is thie CounterModel:: class?

Comment: CounterModel - it is something that conceals:
1. Connect to the database
2. Selection of Collection
It is also that the class MongoDatabase{static function getInstance(){...}} and you call MongoDatabase::getInstance()->selectCollection('counters')->findAndModify

Comment: Maxim, I've tried both $result = MongoDatabase::getInstance()->selectCollection('counters')->findAndModify( and the call to CounterModel but both fail with an error that php can't find that class.  I'm using php 5.6 with the mongo driver 1.6.13

Comment: I beg your pardon, I think it is clear - you need to create a class. As I wrote above - it is something static, it contains MongoClient. you do not have this class.
Once again I am sorry I misled you. I added a function that will work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111757/discussion-between-happydevdays-and-maxim-tkach).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible we have to get max id form collection

```
db->collection->find()->sort(array('id' => -1))->limit(1)
```

It return max id array. Add `db['id'] + 1;`

Every time need not store the auto increment id in mongo